# How do the Iron Man suit thrusters work?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

To fly like Iron Man does, a great deal of energy is needed. Stark solves this by inventing a miniature arc reactor with a new element powering it. Supposing the energy is there, how is it converted to thrust?

Comment: Related, not sure if dupe: [How did Iron Man fly without a big tank of fuel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14478/98028) - see Jack B Nimble's answer to the _how_ with some ion thruster thingy

Comment: @Jenayah - Definitely a dupe.

Comment: @Valorum the dupe-target is apparently limited to the movies. I was unsure of the dupe because OP didn't specify ithe scope they were thinking of - Patrick, were you looking for comics-based references, only movie ones, both?

Comment: @Jenayah - Although the answers refer only to the films, the dupe question isn't limited (hence the use of the generic Marvel tag instead of the MCU tag.

Comment: @Valorum by "dupe question" we're talking about this thread's one right? If so, agree to disagree, OP might just not know their way around the propr tags yet :)

Comment: @Jenayah - The [dupe question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14478/how-did-iron-man-fly-without-a-big-tank-of-fuel) has both MCU and Marvel tags. The fact that both answers have focused on the MCU is neither here nor there.

Comment: @Valorum duly noted then, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: keen's (user1027) highly voted and currently accepted answer on the original touches on the comics version as well. there's room for critique on whether or not that portion is good enough, but he tried to hit on both the MCU and comics version.

Comment: How do the Iron Man suit thrusters work? _[Terribly.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJCUaS8lYjc)_